# How many users you lose when forcing a mobile app update?

Tags: android, ios, analytics, metrics, target-users

I'm evaluating if forcing my android & iOS users to upgrade their apps by disabling the "default functionality" of the app and only showing an "update message" is a good idea.

Thats why I ask to any experienced folks out there: How many users (on average) you lose when forcing an update?

P.S: Any resource that would help me answer this question is welcome!

Comment: I've been through this, and in our case, the answer was "a lot", but it's really going to depend on how critical your app is to their world. Is the app a plaything that they won't miss, or something that helps track daily insulin levels? If they need it, they'll take the steps to upgrade. If not... maybe not as much.